# Why does the existence of a quadrupole moment of the deuteron implies that the nuclear force is not a central force?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, nuclear-physics

Source: Krane and Weisskopf page 95 (the tensor force).

Comment: What makes a central force a central force?

Comment: Central forces magnitude depend on the distance from the origin only

Comment: True, but I was looking for something more than that, something about angular momentum. What is special about central forces and angular momentum.

Comment: Angular momentum is constant?

Comment: Precisely. Does the quadrupole satisfy this condition?

Comment: You're right, quadrupole goes to zero since its spherical harmonic (0-0) is constant. My bad. :(

Answer (score 1):

Because this suggests a force that depends on the orientation of the spins of the nucleons with regard to the vector joining the two nucleons and hence can't be called central force. This force is basically called tensor force.